# Detect if a ContextMenuStrip is displayed or intercepting key events

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

Normally, the concept of Focus as it applies to Winforms controls indicates which control object will receive certain events, particularly keyboard events. However, if a form or one if its controls has a defined `ContextMenuStrip` and the user right-clicks, the menu will temporarily intercept the key press events and prevent them from passing on to the previously `Focused` control.

Note, that in this case, the control in question does not lose focus (or rase a `LostFocus` event), but is rather in some kind of pseudo-unfocused state: e.g, a `TextBox` caret will stop blinking but as soon as the menu is closed will resume normal behavior.

Using a custom control derived from `TextBox`, and overloading `WndProc`, `DefWinProc`, `PreProcessMessage` methods to log all possible Window messages, I see no message to hook on to detect this state.

Calling WinAPI methods `GetForegroundWindow()`, `GetActiveWindow()`, and `Win32.GetFocus()` all return the same handles regardless of whether a context menu is showing.

**My question is:**

Is there any way from a custom user control to detect if the form or any of its controls is currently showing a ContextMenuStrip (ideally without having to iterate over all the controls)?

Comment: The system displays menus running its own modal message loop. That's why you don't get to see messages used by the menu implementation. They are handled before your application even notices, that a message was posted. If you need to know when a popup menu is created and destroyed, set up a [CBT Hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977.aspx) on the GUI thread. Not sure why you think that this is a solution, but this is how you'd do it.

Comment: @IInspectable, does that mean internally controls like `TextBox` are hooking into these events? They seem to know when to stop and restart blinking their caret, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after walking away from this issue for a while and working on something else, I discovered a moderately easy WinAPI approach to solving this problem that plays nicely with C#.

The magic here is the `SetWinEventHook` function from WinAPI:

```
// WINAPI Declarations
const uint EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUSTART = 0x0004;
const uint EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUEND = 0x0005;
const uint EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUPOPUPSTART = 0x0006;
const uint EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUPOPUPEND = 0x0007;

const uint WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0x0000

delegate void WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess, uint idThread, uint dwFlags);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool UnhookWinEvent(IntPtr hWinEventHook);

// Sample Usage - This version will subscribe to menu events on all processes and all threads:
void StartMonitoringMenus()
{
    // The lifetime of these two objects must be the same - we must not let the delegate 
    // get GC'd before calling UnhookWinEvent at the risk of crashing other processes.
    // This sample assumes class fields for these, but could also be static variables
    _menuEventCallback = new WinEventDelegate(MenuEventCallback);
    _menuEventHook = SetWinEventHook(
        EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUSTART,
        EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUPOPUPEND,
        IntPtr.Zero,
        _menuEventCallback,
        0,
        0,
        WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
}

void StopMonitoringMenus()
{
    // Cleanup Logic
    UnhookWinEvent(_menuEventHook);
    _menuEventCallback = null;
}

void MenuEventCallback(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
{
    // Do something here like clear focus on poorly behaving hosted native controls
}
```

The particular sequence of events which get raised depends on the type of menu being displayed.

For MenuStrip controls:

1. MENUSTART
2. MENUPOPUPSTART
3. MENUPOPUPEND
4. ... MENUPOPUPSTART - as the user moves from menu to menu without making a selection
5. ... MENUPOPUPEND
6. MENUEND

For ContextMenuStrips:

1. MENUPOPUPSTART
2. MENUPOPUPEND